# Present data get from tcp on webpage without refreshing entire page?

Tags: php, c++, c, ajax

My php script communicates over TCP with C server, is there a way to present data obtained from the server while it does not refresh the entire page, so the data refer to a ajax script?

Comment: Do you do a call of your PHP script each time you want data from the server or do you want only one PHP script to obtain the data as many times as you want ?

Comment: My idea is to periodically take data from the server and view them on the page, using the time control at the same time, all should be deducted without my request

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ajax or comet is the answer.

(the references to C, C++ and TCP are irrelevant).

But since you've already answered your own question - what's the problem here?